# What are all the runes, and what do they do?

Tags: werewolv.es

What are the runes that have been added to the game thus far, what do they do, and do you have any tips regarding their use?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

These are currently the runes known to be in circulation:

#### Hvísla Rune

A Hvísla Rune allows you to talk to a player the following night. The other player will see all the messages you send at night but will not know who is sending them. Holding it will make you appear as a Witch Craft user to intel checks. After use, a Rune must recharge and can be used again by you three nights later. If you pass the Rune to a different player they will be able to use it immediately.

#### Fela Rune

A Fela Rune allows you to make a player invisible for one night, hiding them from Stalker and Harlot checks. Holding it will make you appear as a Witch Craft user to intel checks. After use, a Rune must recharge and can be used again by you three nights later. If you pass the Rune to a different player they will be able to use it immediately.

#### Sjón Rune

A Sjón Rune allows you to check a player's alignment. Holding it will make you appear as a Witch Craft user to intel checks. After use, a Rune must recharge and can be used again by you three nights later. If you pass the Rune to a different player they will be able to use it immediately.

#### Árvekni Rune

An Árvekni Rune allows you to see everyone that visited a player one night. Holding it will make you appear as a Witch Craft user to intel checks. After use, a Rune must recharge and can be used again by you three nights later. If you pass the Rune to a different player they will be able to use it immediately.

#### Fjät Rune

A Fjät Rune allows you to stalk a player at night to find out who they visit. Holding it will make you appear as a Witch Craft user to intel checks. After use, a Rune must recharge and can be used again by you three nights later. If you pass the Rune to a different player they will be able to use it immediately.

#### Töfrar Rune

A Töfrar Rune allows you to check a whether a player uses Witch Craft or not. Holding it will make you appear as a Witch Craft user to intel checks. After use, a Rune must recharge and can be used again by you three nights later. If you pass the Rune to a different player they will be able to use it immediately.

#### Avleda Rune

An Avleda Rune allows you redirect all visits to a target player to yourself for one night. This includes item usage and item transfers. Holding it will make you appear as a Witch Craft user to intel checks. After use, a Rune must recharge and can be used again by you three nights later. If you pass the Rune to a different player they will be able to use it immediately.